# z-index issue in parent and child element

Tags: css

I need to design the below elements:
1st Parent element - Menu
  Child element - popup
2nd parent element - Body

I need to bring popup to the front then body and then menu.
is this possible?

```
Html
    <div class="menu">
       <div class="popup">
          Test content
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "body-content"></div>
CSS
.menu {
   z-index: -1;
}
```

So now my body content will come front ,menu will go back. But now i tried to click popup div. it just behind the body content. I need to bring that front.

Stack layer
1. Popup
2. Bodycontent
3. Menu

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please take a tour of the help center to see what types of questions are on topic for this site.  It is not a code writing service - you are expected to have a go and if you get stuck with a specific problem, then ask a question, showing what code you have tried and where you have got stuck

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share code in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. 
For better understanding check these demos:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index
https://codepen.io/ajlohman/pen/aJxjH

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is not that easy to understand without an example, code showcase, or any other example.

But I think you can do what you want to do by using negative z-index.

**Edit**: I see you have edited your question, but it is still not that easy to know what you mean.

### But here is my best guess:

http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/rjOzWa

```
.popup {
        /* decoration */
        border: 2px dotted;
        background: rgba(255,125,0,0.6);

        /* place above menu and body-content */
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 30px; /* create overlap for demo */
    }
    .body-content {
        background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
        position: relative;
        z-index: -1;
        bottom: 30px; /* create overlap for demo */
    }
```

```css
div {
 /* just decoration styles */
 width: 350px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 10px 0;
}
.menu {
 background: rgba(50,50,255,0.6); /* opaque background color for understanding */

}
.popup {
 /* smaller for decoration */
 width: 300px; 
 border: 2px dotted;
 background: rgba(255,255,0,0.6);

 /* place above menu and body-content */
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 25px; /* create overlap for demo */
}
.body-content {
 background: rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 bottom: 40px; /* create overlap for demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 Menu Test Content: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.
 <div class="popup">
  Test content popup. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
 </div>
</div>
<div class="body-content">
 Body-Content and more random Text: 
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. <br />body-content test-content: malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.
</div>
```

I think what you want is a popup over everything.
I don't understand the need of having the content above the menu.
But  this is the way I did it.

Note: the `position: relative;` is needed in order to make z-index work on the particular element.

By using relative, the dimensions the element occupies still remain.
If you don't want that, you can define

```
position: absolute;
```

*This makes positioning a little bit trickier, since it is placed to its nearest non-static parent element.*